# I can't access my web server on my NodeMCU devkit over my iPhone

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm quite new to Lua. I have tried to solve the following problem on my own but I couldn't figure it out. Here is my issue:

I'm running a web server on my NodeMCU devkit v0.9. I can easily access the web server on my own computer, but if I try to access the server over my iPhone or using the `requests` module in Python, I always get the message `The network connection was lost.` I'm using the following firmware: nodemcu_float_0.9.6-dev_20150704.

```
print(wifi.sta.getip())
led1 = 3
led2 = 4
gpio.mode(led1, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(led2, gpio.OUTPUT)
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP,30)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
    local buf = "";
    local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
    if(method == nil)then
        _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
    end
    local _GET = {}
    if (vars ~= nil)then
        for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
            _GET[k] = v
        end
    end
    buf = buf.."<h1> ESP8266 Web Server</h1>";
    buf = buf.."<p>GPIO0 <a href=\"?pin=led1\"><button>SWITCH LIGHTS</button></a></p>";
    buf = buf.."<p>"..gpio.read(led1).."</p>";
    local _on,_off = "",""
    if(_GET.pin == "led1")then
        if(gpio.read(led1) == 1) then
            gpio.write(led1, gpio.LOW);
        else 
            gpio.write(led1, gpio.HIGH);
        end
    else end
    client:send(buf);
    client:close();
    end)
end)
```

Comment: The 0.9.x versions are hopelessly outdated and no longer supported. Build your own firmware as per http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/build/ and try again. There's a web server example at https://git.io/vVy4G but that may be removed sooner or later https://git.io/vVy4C.

Comment: Hey okay I solved it. Your solution didn't work out for me. But thank you for taking time to help me !

Comment: So, what was the problem? Please write an answer to your own question so that others may learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by added some information to the beginning of the html buffer. Replace:`local buf=''` with `local buf="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"`

I guess desktop browsers are just more forgiving in this respect.

Comment: you can also create an .html file which you can send instead of the source code.